# Does reactjs batch calls to forceUpdate

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

My component needs to render some data that doesn't live within the component (not in its props or state), and when the component is mounted, it listens to changes in the data and calls https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate

However, the docs suggest this might be bad for performance reasons. Is this because there is no batching in forceUpdate? Instead of calling forceUpdate would I be better calling setState() with the subset of state I need, to hook into reacts batching pipeline?